# Webview load a pdf file display a text look like a blur in Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, webview

[isssue in Webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keBKI.jpg)

I load pdf files using this url  inside a webview     " http://staging-argo.ephronsystems.com/content.php?type=view&docType=category&fileId=49&menuID=44"

in this page contains touch jquery plugin.

Thanks for help

Comment: can you make some commentaire about your problem?

Comment: Please click a link issue in webview you know my problem

Comment: Its not a pdf docs. its created by using html and css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use original pdf file http://staging-argo.ephronsystems.com/admin/uploads/category_files/ARGO BOND REQUEST FORM.pdf 
and for viewing purpose you can use Google Docs Viewer

> [https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://staging-argo.ephronsystems.com/admin/uploads/category_files/ARGO BOND REQUEST FORM.pdf](http://staging-argo.ephronsystems.com/admin/uploads/category_files/ARGO%20BOND%20REQUEST%20FORM.pdf)

Comment: I load this url " http://staging-argo.ephronsystems.com/content.php?type=view&docType=category&fileId=49&menuID=44" inside a webview. In browser display the clear text but not display in webview

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
loadUrl();
```

And loadUrl() ->

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void loadUrl() {
        web.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                web.loadUrl(url);
            }

        });
    }
```

And this.

```
private class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: use url of pdf file not a webpage url. Your url is a webpage created using html and css.

Comment: Its not a pdf docs. its created by using html and css.its using jquery touch plugin android